# Cron works on local host but not when deployed Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I have a cron job in python that works on my localhost but when it is deployed to appengine, it no longer works.

```
  pl = db.Query(Venue).order("id")
    list = pl.fetch(limit=0)
    for p in pl:
        base_url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=100&q=4sq.com/'
        query = p.twitter_ID
        url_string = base_url + query
        json_text = fetch(url_string)
        json_response = simplejson.loads(json_text.content) 
        result = json_response['results']
        for f in result:
            user = f['from_user'] 
            print user
```

This works fine locally but on the server I get the following error:

> 'results' Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/**init**.py",
>   line 515, in **call**
>       handler.get(*groups)   File "/base/data/home/apps/hoosheer/4.347697940058059704/hoosheer_main.py",
>   line 199, in get
>       result = json_response['results'] KeyError: 'results'

This did work until I deployed my second version. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: You need to check what is in the response you get from twitter. I think there is no 'results' field in it, maybe some error occured (some twitter quota exceeded?). Add logging.info('JSON RESPONE: %s' % json_text) to your code and check in application logs what is returned from twitter.

Comment: Yeah, Pawel beat me to it.  I'd bet a reasonable sum of money that Twitter is just counting *all* the requests coming from the App Engines as one user and saying, "No more for you."  You might be allowed to request your own login so as to get a fenced-off quota.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON `'results'` field is not returned because the requests per Ip that Twitter allows has reached the [max quota](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting) of available requests; this explains why from your domestic IP you don't have any problem and you don't get an HTTP 420 response code.

Unluckily Google App Engine uses a shared pool of IP addresses<sup>*</sup> for outgoing urlfetch requests and [Twitter search APIs](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting#search) does not support authentication.

> **Search API Rate Limiting**
>
> Requests to the Search API, hosted on
>   search.twitter.com, do not count
>   towards the REST API limit. However,
>   all requests coming from an IP address
>   are applied to a Search Rate Limit.
>   The Search Rate Limit isn't made
>   public to discourage unnecessary
>   search usage and abuse, but it is
>   higher than the REST Rate Limit. We
>   feel the Search Rate Limit is both
>   liberal and sufficient for most
>   applications and know that many
>   application vendors have found it
>   suitable for their needs.

This would force you to seriously think if Google App Engine is a correct choice for your application.

<sup>*I had the same problem [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/1713/google-app-engine-apps-we-are-all-on-the-same-quota) but luckily the API's developer has enabled an authentication mechanism that allows authenticated requests from the same IP.</sup>

Comment: thanks for your help. I am changing to using Hunch in GAE which shouldn't have the same issues :)